# I want to share file in Dropbox app folder using xamarin forms IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, dropbox, xamarin.forms, dropbox-api

I have implemented Dropbox sync concept using "Dropbox sync and Datastore" component.

For text note it's working fine. But I want to do same thing for files and photos.

```
//Following code will create a file 
DBError error;
        var documents =
            Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments); 
        var filename = Path.Combine (documents, "Write.txt");
        File.WriteAllText (filename, "Write this text into a file");

//Following code for share file on dropbox
DBPath newPath = DBPath.Root.ChildPath(filename);
DBFile archivo = DBFilesystem.SharedFilesystem.CreateFile (newPath,out error);
```

I'm getting exception on last line is **object reference not set to an instance**.

Please assist me.

Comment: A good first step when you get "object reference not set to an instance" is to figure out which object. Sometimes it's obvious from the stack trace. Other times, you might have to check objects individually. For example, is `DBFilesystem.SharedFilesystem` null?

Comment: As an aside, not that the sync and datastore SDKs [have been deprecated](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/04/deprecating-the-sync-and-datastore-apis/) by Dropbox. I'd suggest using the API v2 .NET SDK instead, which you can find here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet.